# How do I get the residual if the data is related to two things?

Tags: correlation, residuals

I have a set of data that is loosely linearly correlated with velocity and also loosely correlated with acceleration. I want to 'subtract' these correlations from the data. If the data was only correlated with velocity, I would just look at the residuals (Rv) after performing a linear fit. However, the data is also somewhat correlated with acceleration. How do I 'remove' both of these correlations?

Do I do the risual of velocity (Rv) and then do the residuals of Rv against acceleration? That seems... not right.

Comment: multiple regression?

Comment: The residual is relative to *predictions from a model* (i.e. $y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i}$: observation minus prediction), *not* relative to a single variable (although single variable models without constant terms can be constructed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments by [Aksakal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428075/how-do-i-get-the-residual-if-the-data-is-related-to-two-things#comment798744_428075) and [Alexis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/428075/how-do-i-get-the-residual-if-the-data-is-related-to-two-things#comment798752_428075): fit any multivariate model to your data, e.g., [multiple regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis), but anything that can model one dependent variable with two independent variables is fine. This covers pretty much every tool you learn about in a statistics or machine learning textbook or course.

Then calculate the fitted value for each observation, using the values of your predictors that correspond to that observation.

Finally, subtract the fits from your actual observations.